# How to read Github's files(specially Markdown files) in React Project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github

**I want to read or embed Markdown files in my React Project? I just try following the code.**

**This Import Section:**

```
import axios from "axios";
import marked from "marked";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Card, CardBody } from "reactstrap";
```

**Then Here Constant and State:**

```
 const url = 'https://github.com/shsohel/ERP/blob/main/ProjectTechnologiies.md';
 const [read, setRead] = useState( null );
```

**Then I am using UseEffect to initial render and get the file from GitHub:**

useEffect( () => {

```
    fetch( url )
        .then( response => {
            return response.text();
        } )
        .then( text => {
            setRead( {
                markdown: marked( text )
            } );
        } );
}, [] );
```

then Here html section:

```
return (
        <div>
            <Card>
                <CardBody dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: read?.markdown }}></CardBody>
            </Card>
        </div>
    );
```

***But I have error in Console: 404 code error! How could I read the file from Github?
Please Help me.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you fetch the markdown as raw data and not just from the page. You can do this by clicking the `Raw` button in the top left on the file's page.
2. It seems you imported `axios` but then just used `fetch`. Make sure to decide on just one of them.

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-wood-ss1yg?file=/src/App.js:528-532) the proposed changes.